# When I gave command on CMD manage.py runserver it instead took me into VS Code and when i ran it in VS code error was on (from django.core.management)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cmd, pip

When I ran the command on CMD `manage.py runserver` it intern redirected to VS Code. When I tried to run on VS Code it showed the system cannot find the specified path. It was underlining this statement:

```
try:
        from django.core.management 
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

1. first you need to add the **python path** to your variable environnement
2. Second
   navigate to your django project and use terminal with this command :

   python manage.py runserver
3. use [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/windows/)